# jQuery selector attribute range

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a table with some rows and cols, each of them hast an attribute:

```
<tr attr-y="1"><td attr-x="1">...</td><td attr-x="2">...</td>...</tr>
<tr attr-y="2"><td attr-x="1">...</td><td attr-x="2">...</td>...</tr>
....
```

Now I want to edit some of these cells and tried to select them by a range, eg. (`attr-y` between 3 and 5, `attr-x = 4`)

```
$('#mytable tr[attr-y>3][attr-y<5] td[attr-x=4]')
```

But that gives me all cells in that column.

Can I select the cells direct (with selector statement)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to perform more complex query:

```
$('#mytable td').filter(function() {
    return ($(this).parent().attr('attr-y') > 3 && $(this).parent().attr('attr-y') < 5)
        && ($(this).attr('attr-x') == 4)
})
.css('background-color', 'aqua');
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8wH4M/1/